# ¿Cómo tomar los dígitos del centro de una cifra numérica?

Tags: c#

tengo que hacer un programa en C# que me calcule números pseudoaleatorios , pero en una parte del procedimiento tengo que tomar 4 dígitos del centro de 8 existentes.
por ejemplo:

Número: 17**8596**42

Dígitos del centro: 8596 (esto es lo que quiero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero que investigues sobre el **método substring** en **C#**.

Básicamente tiene esta estructura:

```
substring(int inicial, int final)
```

Donde inicial es desde donde deseas que empiece la copia de la cadena y final hasta dónde quieres que se copie su forma de llamada sería:

```
string subCadena = cadena.substring(x, y);
```

Lo que quiere decir que en **subCadena** se va a guardar una copia de **cadena** empezando en la posición x y terminando en la posición y.